# `git branch --list` returns files?

Tags: git, scripting, branch, rebase

This is strange. I'm trying to make a script that will checkout every local branch and rebase origin/master onto it.

So this is my script:

```
for br in `git branch -l`; do
    git checkout $br
    git rebase origin/master
done
```

Simple. But before I made the script, I wanted to make sure that `git branch -l` returns what I think it is returning.....it isn't.

`git branch -l` returns the correct result. But `git branch -l` is actually returning all local branch PLUS the files in the current dir!

It returns it like this:

```
[list of local branches minus master] [list of files in the current dir] master
```

`git branch --list` behaves the same way.

Why is this happening?

And is there a better way to rebase origin/master to all local branches?

Comment: you really should not use your custom aliases in a question like this :/

Comment: Just a small remark: I believe what you actually are doing is rebasing all branches onto master, and not the other way around (just a matter of notation)

Comment: Note: make sure to use `git branch --list`: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431590/6309

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is kind of a silly thing.

git branch --list is putting an asterisk in front of the currently selected branch; your shell script is interpreting that as the wildcard and adding the files in the current directory to the list of items to traverse with your for loop.

You can try

```
for br in `git branch -l | tr '*' ' '`; do
    git checkout $br
    git rebase origin/master
done
```

Comment: antlersoft, for the people that do not have br aliased to branch, please substitute br with branch in your answer. I know that your script will work for Nacht, but consider other people that look at this. I gave you an up vote as it does answer Nacht's question. Also consider modifying co to checkout. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The other thing you can do, not really needed here but useful for more robust scripts as it were, is to use `git for-each-ref` to extract the refnames you want.  For instance, the equivalent of `git branch --list` minus the prefix white-space-or-asterisk is:

```
$ git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)'
```

as in this example:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
$ git for-each-ref refs/heads/ --format='%(refname:short)'
master
```

Likewise you can get remotes (`git branch -r`) by using `refs/remotes/` instead of `refs/heads/`, and you can find tags using `refs/tags/`.  There are even extra options with `for-each-ref` designed to protect strings from various program actions (not needed for this particular case, see the documentation for `git check-ref-format` and its restrictions on branch names), but which make it possible to use `eval` on the output of `git for-each-ref`.

Comment: While @antlersoft explained what's causing the problem I prefer the solution here. It seems more robust. :)