# change the branch when the branch not shown in git branch -l

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

When I cloned a remote repository, I used the following command-

```
git clone -b mybranch --single-branch git://sub.domain.com/repo.git
```

After that, when I did a `git branch -l` it just showed me the branch I cloned. Now, I want a pull of another branch, but it is not showing me other branches. What should I do?

Comment: Git 2.20 (Q4 2018) should be faster. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431590/6309).

Answer (score 1):

You can list the branches directly on the remote with `git ls-remote` command:

```
git ls-remote git://sub.domain.com/repo.git
```

Then use `git fetch` command to fetch a specific branch and `git checkout` command to switch to the branch.

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -l` shows you local branches. You want *remote* branches, so try `git branch -r`. When you see the branch you want, you can automatically create and checkout a local branch tracking the given remote branch with `git checkout <remote branch name>`.

For example, if your `git branch -r` shows a branch you want called `origin/my-feature`, just do

```
$ git checkout my-feature
```

Comment: When I do `git branch -r`, It still shows me only the branch I am currently in. Has it got to do with the way I cloned using `--single-branch`?

Comment: Yes. I just tested this with a repository on my machine, and I have the same issue. The answer by @ouah has the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- `git branch --list`, by default, lists local branches, not remote ones (`git branch -r`): you can [create local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309) after those remote ones in order to "see other branches".
- `git branch -l` only lists local branches as a side-effect:

It is *not* the same as `git branch --list`, and '`-l`' will be deprecated with Git 2.19 (Q3 2019).
The "`-l`" option in "`git branch -l`" is an unfortunate short-hand for
["`--create-reflog`"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---create-reflog), but many users, both old and new, somehow expect
it to be something else, perhaps "`--list`".
This step warns when "`-l`" is used as a short-hand for "`--create-reflog`" and warns about the future repurposing of the it when it is used.

See [commit 055930b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/055930bc8960c303ece01d9a34740f25a2a6bba6), [commit 7687f19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7687f19e939dd8c9a2a67ede31b019092f0a1ccf), [commit 6b15595](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b155951510235e7eea77279c7eeea6ac3a8e700) (22 Jun 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d18602f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d18602f4123ad61b094aff5b2822774cf020e70e), 18 Jul 2018)</sup>

> ### `branch`: deprecate "`-l`" option
>
> The "`-l`" option is short for "`--create-reflog`". This has caused much confusion over the years.
>   Most people expect it to work as "`--list`", because that would match the other
>   "mode" options like `-d`/`--delete` and `-m`/`--move`, as well as
>   the similar `-l`/`--list` option of `git-tag`.
>
> Adding to the confusion, using "`-l`" *appears* to work as "`--list`" in some cases:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -l
> * master
> ```
>
> because the branch command defaults to listing (so even trying to specify `--list` in the command above is redundant).
>   But that may bite the user later when they add a pattern, like:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -l foo
> ```
>
> which does not return an empty list, but in fact creates a
>   new branch (with a reflog, naturally) called "foo".
>
> It's also probably quite uncommon for people to actually use "`-l`" to create a reflog. Since [0bee591](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0bee59186976b1d9e6b2dd77332480c9480131d5) (Enable reflogs by default in any repository with a working directory., 2006-12-14 Git v1.5.0), this is the default in non-bare repositories.
>   So it's rather unfortunate that the feature squats on the short-and-sweet "`-l`" (which was only added in [3a4b3f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a4b3f269c4ba1eebd5ab7206ee0915667b20cc8) (Create/delete branch ref logs., 2006-05-19, Git v1.4.0), meaning there were only 7 months where it was actually useful).
>
> Let's deprecate "`-l`" in hopes of eventually re-purposing it to "`--list`".

---

With Git 2.20 (Q2 2018), `-l` is officially short for `--list`.

See [commit 94a1380](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94a13806fbce47de1468a49599ecb901d967aacc) (30 Aug 2018), and [commit a15d598](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a15d598124813a71f0a221b4fcabeb75f40aebd7) (22 Jun 2018) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7dc341c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7dc341cedb66746710ce51ac5f8416089445c448), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>